# Prove convergence of: $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\cdot\sqrt{n}}{(n+1)\cdot2^n}\cdot(x-3)^n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to prove the convergence of series: $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\cdot\sqrt{n}}{(n+1)\cdot2^n}\cdot(x-3)^n $$ for every x $\in \mathbb{R}$. I am a bit lost on this one. I tried using alternating series test, but showing that the series is decreasing proved to be a bit complicated and it doesn't prove absolute convergence.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not try to find the radius of convergence in the usual way?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't converge for every $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Quickly using the divergence test, we find that the terms don't go to zero for $x<1$ and $x>5$

**Hint:** Use the ratio test or the root test to prove that it converges when $1<x<5$.

To find the convergence at $x=1$ and $x=5$, use the $p$-test and alternating series test, respectively.

Comment: what is p-test? I cannot use integrals yet

Comment: @Mykybo And when you use the Ratio test, you may conveniently "ignore" the radical and the $n+1$ term as these "polynomials" don't contribute to establishing the boundary values. That makes the Test lots quicker...